# How to summarize GPS tracks into a single line of equidistant points?

Tags: geolocation, gps, k-means, path-finding, geo

I am looking forward to advice on GPS data. Recorded are several tracks which branch out. I would like to summarize this data so that only one line of points summarizes the traveled route. The points should have as far as possible the same distance.

[raw gps points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEw7K.png)

A pragmatic solution for me was a k-mean clustering. Here, however, the distance problem is not given and the computational effort is high.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezeoe.png)

```
def cluster_kmean(frames):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=400, random_state=0, n_init='auto')
    kmeans.fit(frames[['lon', 'lat']])
    centroids_dict = {'lon': kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,0], 'lat': kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,1], 'videoID': 'cluster'}
    centroids = pd.DataFrame(centroids_dict)
    return centroids
```

Are there other known methods that solve my problem? Can particle filters or similar be a solution?
Im moer than helpfull for advice on where to look next.

Julian